# calculating how many bits an integer takes in C

Tags: c, bit

I am working on this short algorithm that prompt the user to type an integer and the output will be how many bits that integers takes: However when I enter very large numbers the output turns negative. I do not wish to have negative output. How can I fix this? Also is there a better way to apply this process?

```
 int numberHowBig =0;
printf("How many Bits? ");
scanf(" %d", &numberHowBig);
printf("n\n");


int myIncrementor = 1, myMultiplier = 1,
    finalValue = 1;
while (myIncrementor < numberHowBig){
    myMultiplier *=2;
    finalValue = finalValue + myMultiplier;
    myIncrementor++;
}
if ((numberHowBig == 0) || (numberHowBig == 1)){
    printf("Top value: %d\n\n", numberHowBig);
} else {
    printf("Top value: %d\n\n", finalValue);
}
```

Comment: Try `long` and format specifier `%ld`. There will always be a machine limitation, unless you read the number as a string.

Comment: You must take overflow, the fact that `int` is signed and the largest number which can fit your chosen type into consideration. Mind that you can simply shift the number to right and count how many shifts are required to make it `0` to obtain the same result, eg `int s = 0; while (number >>= 1) ++s;`

Answer (score 0):

You can print the unsigned int version of your numbers by using %u instead of %d.
Your problem arises from the fact that the "int" type is limited to 4 bytes of memory, and you increment it exponentially (by adding myMultiplier), so it gets too big for 4 bytes so it messes things up.

Comment: An `int` is not "limited to 4 bytes", but must be _at least_ 16 bits wide, with no upper limit specified in the Standard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way. You can use bitwise shifting like this:

```
if ((numberHowBig == 0) || (numberHowBig == 1)){
    printf("Top value: %d\n\n", numberHowBig);
} else {
    int finalValue = (1 << numberHowBig) - 1;
    printf("Top value: %d\n\n", finalValue);
}
```

And if you want to able to handle bigger output, use a bigger [datatype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).

Answer (score 0):

> Also is there a better way to apply this process?

One better way (for positive numbers) is to cast the number to an unsigned and then count how many right shifts it takes to reduce it to zero. If you started with zero, that is a special case and the answer is 1 bit.

Negative numbers are more problematic, do you count 1's or 0's? In the first case, the answer is "the bit width of the type", but some of the 1's will just be sign extension bits, do they really count? In the second case, just cast to unsigned, take the bitwise negation and repeat the process for positive numbers.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I would. It occurs to me that this assumes a 2's complement representation.

Answer (score 0):

using libmath this is an alternative:

```
printf( "Top Value %u \n",
    (unsigned int) exp2((double) numberHowBig)-1 );
```